# Receiving run-time error '9'

Tags: vba, excel

I have just started to learn how to program using Python about a month ago and I am trying to learn a bit about VBA as well. I have an excel document with 3 sheets, the first being an inventory with columns A through W and several thousand rows. The second sheet is the assets that are in question, the third is the destination for the results.

This is the pseudo code for the macro:

- Make the second sheet active
- Create Loop to go through contents of column A and highlight each
- Copy contents of each row to variable one by one
- Make the first sheet active
- Loop through the contents of Column C and D for aforementioned variable
- If found highlight the active row
- Copy active row to sheet 3 in next available row starting at A

I have researched how to solve this problem for the last several days, finding code for searching, looping through rows, selecting the appropriate row, going between sheets for the copy command. With all of this I have written what I believe should work for the intended purpose. I have included comments for each line to give my thought process behind it.

The error I'm receiving currently: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
Error location: Line 12 - where I set the targetsheet to Sheet(0).

Thank you so much for any help!

```
Sub SpecialCopy()
  Dim targetSh, destinationSh, invSh As Worksheet
  Set targetSh = Sheets(1)  'Setting initial value to Page 2 which contains assets being searched for
  Set destinationSh = Sheets(2)   'Using a second one for use in the final copy statement to the destination sheet
  Dim i As Long
  Dim g As Long
  Dim asset As String 'Using string as asset row may contain all numbers or numbers and letters

  For g = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'Using loop to loop through values in column containing assets being searched for
    Set targetSh = Sheets(1)
    asset = Cells(g, 1).Value  'Setting asset to next value in Sheet 2
    Set targetSh = Sheets(0) 'Not sure if I should initialize a third worksheet to use as the worksheet containing inventory, or if setting it twice in the loop would work.
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row  'Looping through values in inventory to find asset
      If Cells(i, 3).Value = asset Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 23)).Copy Destination:=destinationSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1)  'Trying to copy the found asset, including all rows from A to W from Sheet(0) to Sheet(2)
      End If
    Next i
  Next g
End Sub
```

The code can be found on Github here: https://github.com/cookchelsea/Find_and_Paste/blob/master/Master

Comment: there is no sheet at position 0

Comment: There is no sheets(0) in a worksheets collection. The index starts at 1.

Comment: `targetSh` is being redundantly assigned twice, once illegally (index 0), and then redundantly re-assigned at every iteration of the `g` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point for sheets is Sheet(1), so pointing to Sheet(0) is getting you Run-time error 9, which in this case is because you a referencing a non-existent collection (there is no Sheet(0)). More on that error code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx).